# Set Postgres DMY

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

i'm reading a file with many lines and mounting insert queries with a generic config in runtime, because the inserts is for more than one enity, the idea is that the database automatically deal with the types in the query. Here's the problem, the date format: **12022016** (DMY) i do like to now if its possible to make Postgres to accept that format in the insert's queries.

**EX:**

```
INSERT INTO TEST(1,'12022016');
```

(Sorry if i talk something wrong, not english speaker here :)

Comment: `INSERT INTO TEST select 1,to_date('12022016','DDMMYYYY');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting custom format for date is not too obvious. Just `set datestyle to DMY;` wont solve your problem - [look here fro details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datetime-appendix.html), I'd try transformation on load, like here:

```
t=# select to_date('12022016','DDMMYYYY')::date;
  to_date
------------
 2016-02-12
(1 row)
```

so for you it would be:

```
INSERT INTO TEST select 1,to_date('12022016','DDMMYYYY');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that i'm generating insert queries with a generic config, because the inserts is for more than one enity, the idea is that the database automatically deal with the types in the query. But if you know another way to insert date without using functions on the queries i do like to now :) (Sorry for any errors)

Comment: for that you can use `RULE` or trigger... And if it is one-time operation you can add date column and update its value using text column... You should put all that to your question...

Comment: Sorry, i tried to be succinct to avoid mistakes in the question because my bad english, yeah i'll be implementing something like that, thanks.

Comment: you can update your question -I'll try to help you If I can

Comment: its more understandable now?

Comment: yes, it is. yet, I don't have simple and safe solution for setting custom datestyle

Comment: Yeah solve in database its gonna be hard, i'm thinking in some logic on the application to detect the date type. Well... i'll find a way